# How to save base64 file to the client using JavaScript?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have the gotten a certain result from the Notes tab.

The link you see inside the iframe is the name of the file.

I have the DocumentBody from the annotation in some format that looks like base64.

How do I download it?

[image: Save base64 string to the client as a file]

Thanks,
Fabio

Comment: if you post a little of HTML we could understand better

Comment: Possible dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274456/how-to-create-a-text-file-on-a-client-machine-using-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: @GregOwens, the answer to your question is no, it's not a dupe. Even if the solution would be the same. The keywords used are not the same. So someone looking for these keywords will never find the other question. Besides, the question is not the same (even if the answer would). Try contributing instead of just trying to look smart by looking for other similar questions. Dupe syndrome is the only problem with this site.

Comment: C# example: http://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2012/07/28/exporting-annotation-note-attachment/

Comment: @JamesWood, thanks for the link but I was looking for a JavaScript solution.

Comment: Calm down Fabio, no need for such an aggressive tone ;) I contribute plenty as my profile attests. By finding a potential dupe I am potentially answering your question. In this case, you disagree that it's a dupe (Though you want to save a binary file to the client machine using Javascript. It sure *sounds* like the same thing). There's no need to get all sulky!

Comment: Sorry if I seemed too aggressive. Didn't mean that but this is not a duplicate.

Comment: @FabioMilheiro That's why I didn't add as an answer, related information might come in handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had already the base64 documentbody string extracted like this:

```js
function getSla() {
    // Define SOAP message
    var objectId;
    if (typeof crmForm === "undefined") {
        objectId = parent.crmForm.ObjectId;
    }
    else {
        objectId = crmForm.ObjectId;
    }

    var xml =
        [
        "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>",
        "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" ",
        "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" ",
        "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">",
        GenerateAuthenticationHeader(),
        "<soap:Body>",
        "<RetrieveMultiple xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2007/WebServices'>",
        "<query xmlns:q1='http://schemas.microsoft.com/crm/2006/Query' ",
        "xsi:type='q1:QueryExpression'>",
        "<q1:EntityName>annotation</q1:EntityName>",
        "<q1:ColumnSet xsi:type='q1:AllColumns' />",
        "<q1:Distinct>false</q1:Distinct><q1:Criteria><q1:FilterOperator>And</q1:FilterOperator>",
        "<q1:Conditions><q1:Condition><q1:AttributeName>objectid</q1:AttributeName><q1:Operator>Equal</q1:Operator>",
        "<q1:Values><q1:Value xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">",
        objectId,
        "</q1:Value></q1:Values></q1:Condition></q1:Conditions></q1:Criteria>",
        "</query>",
        "</RetrieveMultiple>",
        "</soap:Body>",
        "</soap:Envelope>"
        ].join("");
    var resultXml = executeSoapRequest("RetrieveMultiple", xml);

    var result = filter(resultXml.getElementsByTagName("q1:filename"), function (element) {
        return /master.*sla/i.test(element.text);
    });

    if (result.length == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return result[0].parentNode;
    }
}

function getSlaDocumentBody(sla) {
    return sla.getElementsByTagName("q1:documentbody")[0].text;
}

window.open("data:application/pdf;base64," + getSlaDocumentBody(sla));
```

It opened a new window with the string data:application/pdf.......... in the address bar but did nothing. I would prefer that solution indeed.

Ended up using srasmussen solution in here: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crm/thread/05134277-dd76-4fbb-8f6e-89b1a2a45af1.

```js
var URL = serverUrl + "/userdefined/edit.aspx?etc=5&id=" + slaId;

$.get(URL, function (data) {
    var WRPCTokenElement = $(data).find("[WRPCTokenUrl]");
    if (WRPCTokenElement) {
        var WRPCTokenUrl = WRPCTokenElement.attr("WRPCTokenUrl");
        if (WRPCTokenUrl) {
            URL = "/Activities/Attachment/download.aspx?AttachmentType=5&AttachmentId=" + slaId + "&IsNotesTabAttachment=undefined" + WRPCTokenUrl;
            window.open(URL);
        }
    }

    return false;
});
```

Comment: I am busy working on something similar to preserve inline images in email activity responses. I will post when I have it properly solved. I have the Base64 png and can display it. Do you have the Base64 pdf text in a variable?

Comment: Yes @Bvrce, I have it. I get it from q1:documentbody as you can see in my answer. Thanks! Looking forward to your insight.

Answer (score 1):

Perform a JQuery request to a URL like this

```
Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl() + "XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ActivityMimeAttachmentSet(guid'abc...')?$select=Body"
```

By specifying the select you will request only what you want.

Assign the result to a variable and prepend

```
data:application/pdf;base64,
```

From there you could display it inline as an HTML object or try to open it as a new window with

```
window.location or window.open or document.location.href
```

Comment: Is it ActivityMimeAttachmentSet where the pdf is located? DO you have the GUID of the PDF? You can use Document.body.all.tags('a') and inspect the href attribute to find where the link is pointing to.

Comment: I am fairly certain that he means to **prepend** 'data:application/pdf;base64,' See the trailing comma?

Comment: @Bvrce, I got another solution, but I will accept your solution (which I had already tried) if you can show it is possible to do that. Please check my answer to see the problem I faced. Thanks. +1